# Script runs very slow via Scheduled task

Tags: powershell, windows-10-iot-core

My PowerShell script takes a snapshot from IP camera, it runs on a Raspberry Pi3 with Windows 10 IoT Core.

When I run the script from PowerShell (only type `c:\scripts\snapshot.ps1`) it's running great. But when I run it from cmd `powershell -File c:\scripts\snapshot.ps1` (I need this for running from task scheduler), it's running too much time and take whole CPU core and after few minutes running I kill it.

The same when I run this command from powershell (no from cmd). Script will stop on `Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Headers $Headers -OutFile "$dir\$outFile"`. The file `$outFile` is created, but with no content and still running and running. I observe whole script is too slow, when run script only with 2 `Write-Output`, it's delay between 2 written strings.
I tried `-MTA` and `-NoProfile` and some next `powershell.exe` argument, but with no luck.

My script:

```
$user = 'operator'
$pass = 'password'
$url = 'http:\\url.jpg'
$dir = "c:\outputdir"

$date = Get-Date
$date = $date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss")

$outFile = "snapshot_$date.jpg"

$pair = "$($user):$($pass)"

$encodedCreds = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($pair))

$basicAuthValue = "Basic $encodedCreds"

$Headers = @{
    Authorization = $basicAuthValue
}

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Headers $Headers -OutFile "$dir\$outFile"
```

EDIT:
My scheduled task to run:

```
Folder: \
HostName:                             pi
TaskName:                             \Create-snapshot
Next Run Time:                        3/27/2017 3:32:00 AM
Status:                               Running
Logon Mode:                           Interactive/Background
Last Run Time:                        3/27/2017 3:31:02 AM
Last Result:                          267009
Author:                               pi\Administrator
Task To Run:                          C:\Data\Admin\Create-Snapshot\Create-Snapshot-Start.bat >> "c:\Data\Admin\Create-Snapshot\Log\Create-Snapshot-start 2017-03-27  2_47_25.log"
Start In:                             N/A
Comment:                              N/A
Scheduled Task State:                 Enabled
Idle Time:                            Disabled
Power Management:                     Stop On Battery Mode, No Start On Batteries
Run As User:                          Administrator
Delete Task If Not Rescheduled:       Disabled
Stop Task If Runs X Hours and X Mins: 72:00:00
Schedule:                             Scheduling data is not available in this format.
Schedule Type:                        One Time Only, Minute 
Start Time:                           12:56:00 AM
Start Date:                           3/27/2017
End Date:                             N/A
Days:                                 N/A
Months:                               N/A
Repeat: Every:                        0 Hour(s), 1 Minute(s)
Repeat: Until: Time:                  None
Repeat: Until: Duration:              Disabled
Repeat: Stop If Still Running:        Disabled
```

I tried run task as NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM - but no luck.

Thank you for your time.

Rob

Comment: How do you have the task configured? Are you using switches like `-NoProfile`? There are lots of things that load with PowerShell by default that would be doing the same in a configured task if not omitted. Most examples of making powershell into tasks would cover this.

Comment: i'm trying powershell -NoProfile -File "c:\Data\Admin\Create-Snapshot\Create-Snapshot.ps1" - when run from powershell remote with this command or from scheduled task it's slow and when i run it from cmd or directly open .ps1 script in powershell ISE and run, it's ok..

Comment: This looks similar to http://serverfault.com/questions/151824/process-runs-slower-as-a-scheduled-task-than-it-does-interactively

Comment: I think no because there is not only problem with scheduled task but with running "powershell -File c:\scripts\snapshot.ps1" from remote powershell too.

Comment: and i don't know if it's "slower". Invoke-WebRequest takes about few second normally, but from scheduled task or calling powershell -NoProfile -File "c:\Data\Admin\Create-Snapshot\Create-Snapshot.ps1" from powershell ISE takes... I don't know how much time, I killed it longest after 30 minutes.. It can be jammed somewhere but why powershell process eats whole CPU core all time processing Invoke-Request?

Comment: Thought of Executing as background JOb from the task scheduler? if not, please try using start-job and see

Comment: thank you, but it seems like doesn't work. Not understanding why and I'm so frustated:(

Comment: Have you tried remove Invoke-WebRequest line for testing?  And what about on desktop?

Comment: Hello Rita, yes, i removed Invoke-Request line and script was slowly than in Remote Powershell (via PS ISE) but it rans okay. On my desktop in windows 10 Pro with all updates it runs okay too. I have raspi updated with all updates too. I Think It seems like a bug in Powershell in Windows 10 IoT Core.. :(

Comment: okay, i tried develop UAW app rather powershell and.. on httpClient.GetAsync(requestUri) is the same problem - never ending while visual studio stop debug. Internet and lan working, ping and DNS are okay. I tried Inssider build of Windows 10 and the same problem exists. I don't know where can be problem:(

Comment: `httpClient.GetAsync()` doesn't have the issue for me. Can you provide your code?

Comment: For powershell script, it looks like powershell.exe take much resources(cpu and memory) because no matter you run `powershell -File c:\scripts\snapshot.ps1` from powershell or cmd tool(I use putty). You can check processes and performance in [device portal](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/docs/deviceportal).

Answer (score 9):

By default any task runs with "Below Normal" Priority.

If you export your task out of task scheduler and open the XML you will see:

```
<Priority>7</Priority>
```

Change this to:

```
<Priority>4</Priority>
```

Save the XML, delete the task and run the "Import Task". Point at your edited XML and you should find the task now runs with Normal Priority.

You can check the priority by finding the instance of PowerShell in Task manager, right click and choose "Set priority".